# Open Form and Close Form with Checkbox

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to open and close/show and hide a form named "InfoOverLay" using a metro checkbox.
But every time the box gets checked it creates a new version of its self.

How could I change this to open and close only one version of itself?

```
    private void metroChecker1_CheckedChanged(object sender, bool isChecked)
    {
        if (metroChecker1.Checked == true)
        {
            InfoOverLay f = new InfoOverLay();
            f.Show();
        }
        if (metroChecker1.Checked == false)
        {
            InfoOverLay f = new InfoOverLay();
            f.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: Have you try to not create a **new** instance of `InfoOverLay` on each click? Store it in a private field.

Comment: try `Application.OpenForms[formName] as Form` before you create a new form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private InfoOverLay f = new InfoOverLay(); 
private void metroChecker1_CheckedChanged(object sender, bool isChecked)
{
    if (metroChecker1.Checked == true)
    {
         f.Show();
    }
    if (metroChecker1.Checked == false)
    {
        f.Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional check to see if it's already open
pseudo code:

```
if (alreadyIsActive)
  operationCancel();
```

Also make sure you aren't calling multiple instances of it's self like  – vasily.sib said which can be done like:

```
 private void metroChecker1_CheckedChanged(object sender, bool isChecked)
    {
        InfoOverLay f = new InfoOverLay();
        if (metroChecker1.Checked == true)
        {
            f.Show();
        }
        if (metroChecker1.Checked == false)
        {
            f.Hide();
        }
```

Have a good day!

Comment: this code do the same thing as that code in a question. You are still creating a **new** instance of `InfoOverLay` on every click